# Rewrite and Redirect conflict issue

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting

> Can we implement rewrite and redirect rules on the same URL.
>
> I am using below code right now.
>
> Project root folder: test
>   Old Page: about-us.php
>   New Page: about/support/
>
> ```
> Redirect 301 /test/about-us.php http://localhost/test/about/support/
> RewriteRule ^about/support/ about-us.php
> ```
>
> So if I write about/support/ as a URL, the old page will open keeping the > new URL with URL rewrite.
>   And if some one come with external old link about-us.php, he will be > redirected to new page http://localhost/test/about/support/
>
> If I use above code in htaccess, I stuck into the redirection loop. And 
>   getting error message: Page is not 
>   redirecting properly. Can someone please help.